# NodeJS, Express, MongoDB - pass multiple Mongoose queries to rendered page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Working on a rather simple to-do app, where I plan to have three columns on a site based on status; "Pending", "In progress", "Done".

My model looks like this:

```
var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: String
});
```

And on the new post route, there is a dropdown to select Status.

Now when I render the index page, showing the three columns, I guess I can either do three mongoose queries, one foreach status, or have one query which return all "Tasks" and filter them in Javascript on the index-page itself. (Using EJS by the way).

I tried the following to create a function which take a parameter "status", and then does a mongoose query based on this.
Then create a variable which call this function, and pass it by when rendering the page.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
function getTasks(status){
    var query = Task.find({ status:status});
    return query;
}
var pending = getTasks('pending');
console.log(pending);
res.render("tasks/index", {tasks: pending});
});
```

And in the index I have a simple:

```
<% tasks.forEach(function(task){ %>
    <li><%= task.title %></li>
<%})%>
```

However running this results in an error:

```
TypeError: c:\x\Dev\ToDo\views\tasks\index.ejs:3
    1| <% include ../partials/header %>

    2| 

 >> 3| <% tasks.forEach(function(task){ %>

    4|     <li><%= task.title %></li>

    5| <%})%>

    6| <div class="container-fluid">


tasks.forEach is not a function
    at eval (eval at compile (c:\Users\x\Dev\ToDo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:22:14)
```

Any thoughts what is the best way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose.find()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) method returns a `Promise` object.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  function getTasks(status) {
    return Task.find({
      status,
    });
  }

  getTasks('pending')
    .then((docs) => {
      console.log(docs);

      res.render('tasks/index', {
        tasks: docs,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       console.error(err);
    });
});
```